# Haskell profiling options result in build error of "Cannot load -prof objects when GHC is built with -dynamic"

Tags: haskell, cabal, nix

I wanted to do some profiling on a Haskell application so in my hpack I added some `ghc-options`:

```
  example-executable:
    source-dirs: src
    main: Main.hs
    ghc-options:
      - -O2
      - -prof
      - -fprof-auto
      - -rtsopts
```

that resulted in this error:

```
[ 6 of 19] Compiling Model.Server     ( src/Model/Server.hs, dist/build/discord-app-prof/discord-app-prof-tmp/Model/Server.o )
<no location info>: error:
    src/Model/Server.hs:125:13: fatal:
    Cannot load -prof objects when GHC is built with -dynamic
    To fix this, either:
      (1) Use -fexternal-interpreter, or
      (2) Build the program twice: once with -dynamic, and then
          with -prof using -osuf to set a different object file suffix.
```

Where is this `-dynamic` coming from? I don't recall ever running into this issue before when profiling previously which is also strange. Also it's confusing when it says "GHC is built with -dynamic" - surely GHC is not being built here but the haskell executable?

I'm using GHC 9.0.2

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `-fprof-auto` is a bad idea. Every time I've used it or seen anyone use it, it gives wrong results. Profiling requires tagging code with cost centers, but cost centers inhibit many optimizations. You end up measuring code that is different from what actually executes on a normal run. (Code that's actually fast can appear much slower, so your optimization priorities will be mixed up.) I strongly recommend picking a different profiling option, or writing `SCC` annotations yourself. Perhaps you can try the new [`-fprof-late`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/profiling.html#ghc-flag--fprof-late) (though this requires GHC 9.4.1).

`-dynamic` is the default because dynamic linking is the default on your OS (as it is on all the popular PC OSs). "GHC is built with `-dynamic`" means exactly that; the GHC binaries you're using *were* (in the past, before you downloaded them or perhaps when you built them yourself) built with `-dynamic`. You of course aren't rebuilding GHC now.

Profiling requires not just your own code be built with `-prof`, but that all dependencies also be built with `-prof`. This is something the build system (Cabal) needs to orchestrate, to create and then point GHC at the correct files. You can't just throw `-prof` into `ghc-options`. In the very simplest case, if you were using bare `cabal-install`, you just need to add the following to `cabal.project.local`. I believe `cabal configure --enable-profiling --profiling-detail=late` would write out such a file too. You do *not* put `-prof -fprof-late` into `ghc-options`.

```
profiling: True
profiling-detail: late
```

The next `cabal build` of the project will (re)build all dependencies as needed with profiling. I believe Cabal also uses `-dynamic-too` to get the `-dynamic` and `-prof` versions of the objects simultaneously and avoids the GHC error you saw by pointing e.g. `ghci` at the `-dynamic` objects when requested. You can control the profiling detail in dependencies through `cabal.project.local`, too. (The way it stands, this file applies a default of `-fprof-auto-exported` to all dependencies.)

Note that the `.cabal` file wasn't touched. In the Cabal model, profiling is not part of the package description. Profiling is, after all, not part of the package content. Profiling is just a special way of building the package. (I note that you have `-O2` in `ghc-options` too. This is also anti-Cabal. The correct way to handle *that* is to put `optimization: 2` into `cabal.project.local`, probably under a `package *` stanza to apply it to all dependencies as well as the current package.) The only option that *should* be in `ghc-options` out of those you have listed is `-rtsopts`.

I don't use hpack, but it looks to me that it only generates the `.cabal` file (i.e. it *just* describes the package). As (reiterating) profiling and optimization are *not* properties of the package but properties of the build, you don't do anything to your hpack configuration to use them. You just write the appropriate `cabal.project.local` and use that besides the `.cabal` generated by hpack. I'm not sure what complications Nix adds here.

NB: There is a distinction between build configuration that should ship with the package and configuration local to the developer. The former goes in `cabal.project`, the latter into `cabal.project.local`. In order for `cabal.project.local` to be processed correctly, you may need a trivial `cabal.project` that contains simply `packages: .`.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution was to change my `default.nix`, the `-dynamic` is probably being set as a default somewhere:

```
- myHaskellPackages.callCabal2nix "HaskellNixCabalStarter" (src) {}
+ myHaskellPackages.callCabal2nixWithOptions "HaskellNixCabalStarter" (src) "--enable-profiling" {}
```

As mentioned here: [How can I enable Haskell profiling when using Nix's callCabal2nix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58891928/how-can-i-enable-haskell-profiling-when-using-nixs-callcabal2nix)